# Can prepositional phrase have verbs and subjects in it?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

“I need information on how I can help.”

I have read that prepositional phrases either lack a verb or a subject. This sentence seems to have both. Would this be correct and if so is the object of preposition “how I can help”?

Comment: The Preposition Phrase is "on how I can help". Here the head is a preposition - "on", which takes an open interrogative finite content clause as its complement - "how I can help". The preparation phrase is however part of the noun phrase - information on how I can help", where the head os a noun - "information" and the preposition phrase is the complement of the head. Now some grammarian uses the term "object of the preparation" but some reserves the term "object" for the verb only. Anyway object is also a complement. So it is safe to use "complement of the preparation" here.

Answer (score 3):

Noun clauses with subjects and verbs can be objects of prepositions. See
[englishgrammar101 *noun clause*](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-10/clauses/lesson-5/noun-clauses)

> A noun clause is a dependent clause that acts as a noun. It can be used as the subject, direct object, indirect object, **object of a preposition**, subject complement, or appositive.

[emphasis added]

Comment: Noun clauses are also known as *free relative clauses*.